# ExpandableListViewFragment

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an application in which two fragments are within one activity.

One is `ExpandableListViewFragment` and the other is the corresponding layout fragment.

The first fragment will display the `expandableListItem` on click on any of the items either group or child. Then a layout corresponding to that item (`expandableListItem`) will inflate in other fragment. I did these using `ListView` but not on `ExpandableListView`.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Pk

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is:

ExpandableListView, an adapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter, and corresponding layouts both for the groupView and the child views.

Extending BaseExpandableListAdapter forces you to implement a few methods, but once you think about them, it's not really that hard to understand.

The trick is all inside the adapter. You can inflate both a layout for the parent and the children.
Check out my example:

This way, you have the parent view inflated with the parent layout, and the children also with their correpinding layouts.
Hope it helps.

```
public class ExpadableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
Activity context;

List<Movie> listObjects;

private static LayoutInflater inflaterParent = null;
private static LayoutInflater inflaterChild = null;

private ImageLoader imageLoader; 
//on the constructor pass on the list of objects
public ExpadableAdapter(Activity context, List<Object> listObjects) {
    context = context;
    this.listObjects = listObjects; 
    inflaterParent = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflaterChild = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    //in this case I fetch the children on a DB, you can as well have a two dimensions array at first
    List<Day> parentChildren = DBUtils.getObjectChildren(context, listObjects.get(groupPosition).getId());
    return parentChildren.get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Object object = listObjects.get(groupPosition);
    //the first inflation for children views
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflaterChild.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);

    List<Day> listChildren = DBUtils.getChildren(context, listObjects.get(groupPosition).getId());

    TextView textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.child_layout_textview);
    return vi;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return listObjects.get(groupPosition).getCount();
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return listObjects.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return listObjects.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    //the parent inflater.
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflaterParent.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, null);

    TextView textView=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout_text_view);;
    textView.setText(listObjects.get(groupPosition).getName());

    return vi;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```